# How to set cloud based SMTP details in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have send email functionality in my code and I have cloud based SMTP details like follows 
SMTP Server:xxxxxxxxx
SMTP User:xxxxxxxx
SMTP Password:xxxxxx
SMTP Port:25
SMTP Enable SSL:true

but in the c# we required to set following details

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("<email address>");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("<email address>");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from,to);
```

but I have cloud based system's SMTP details and don't have from email Id therefore the code is throwing an error that from email is must.
Any solution for it?

Comment: The _fromEmail_ address can be any value, it doesn't have to match the SMTP. It's simply there to allow recipients to reply.

Comment: yes, but it throws an error if I only pass this type of string "ABC"

Comment: My mistake, the _fromEmail_ address can be any **email address**. Set it to something like `testing@example.com`.

Comment: I tried with above but getting following error,
Transaction failed. The server response was: Message rejected: Email address is
not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: testing@example.com

Comment: Sounds to me that your cloud provider should (or has) given you the from email you should be using.

Comment: Please don't use the term ASP.NET 5. It's not called like this anymore. The name is ASP.NET Core. Also MVC6 is called ASP.NET Core MVC. Using wrong tags leads to people not noticing your question and you not getting any replies